# How to write SQL query where one column returns multiple results C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, razor

I have two tables:

users:

```
ID    Name
----------------
1     Bob
2     Dave
3     Mike
```

Books:

```
ID  UserId   BookName
------------------------
1    1       Cat in Hat
2    1       Happy Birthday
3    1       One Fish
4    2       Goldilocks
5    2       Three Crows
6    3       Hitchhikers
```

UserId is a key showing which books each user owns

In my html I want to create output that looks like this:

```
Name       Books Owned
-------------------------
Bob        Cat in Hat, Happy Birthday, One Fish
Dave       Goldilocks, Three Crows
Mike       Hitchhikers
```

Currently I am doing this with a loop and nested query:

```
var queryusers = db.Query("SELECT * FROM users");

foreach (var user in queryusers) {
    <span>@user.name</span>
    var querybooks = db.Query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE userid = @0", user.id);
    foreach (book in querybooks ) {
        <span>@book.bookname</span>
    }
}
```

I know that's not good, but I don't know how to do this with JOIN. If I try:

```
var queryusersandbooks = db.Query("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN books ON users.id = books.userid");
```

My query returns 6 rows, but I only want 3. Is there a way to do this without having a SQL query in the loop?

Thanks

Comment: Can you reformat your table/field descriptions?  I can't even understand what it's supposed to look like..

Comment: me too   in your last row seems you want the book of an user without say who is the user ..is sql..

Comment: You could use the query that uses JOIN and then group items by user id and iterate through the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Try something like this:

```
SELECT name AS Name, GROUP_CONCAT(books.bookname SEPARATOR ', ') AS Books 
FROM books INNER JOIN users ON users.id=books.userid 
GROUP BY books.userid;
```

Keep in mind that `GROUP-CONCAT` has a 1024 character limit, so if you need more space, set a bigger threshold before executing the SQL, like this:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT name AS Name, GROUP_CONCAT(books.bookname SEPARATOR ', ') AS Books 
FROM books INNER JOIN users ON users.id=books.userid 
GROUP BY books.userid;
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dabb5/10).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT u.name,CONCAT_WS(',',b.bookname) AS user_books FROM users u INNER JOIN books b ON u.id = b.userid GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to do something like this in mysql, I'd group by user and use group_concat to combine the results:

```
select users.id, users.name, group_concat(bookname) as books
from users inner join books on books.userid = user.id
group by users.id, users.name
```

You can order and specify the separator if you like, read about [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for more details. This breaks down quickly if there might be a lot of books, or if you want each book to be its own column or anything like that, but it's fine in simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. In your original code the inner foreach would have executed 6 times as well, once for each of the books.

Using the code below (basing off your own code), the query would still return 6 rows, as you have found, but only prints the user name once.

```
var queryusersandbooks = db.Query("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN books ON users.id = books.userid ORDER BY users.name");

int curruser = 0;
foreach (var userandbook in queryusersandbooks)
{
    if (userandbook.userid != curruser)
    {
        <span>@userandbook.name</span>
        curruser = userandbook.userid;
    }
    <span>@userandbook.bookname</span>
}
```